# Loop SpeechRecognizer in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I would loop the speech recognition of my app.
I used this code to start the recognition of my speech.

http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/

Now I would re-start the recognition suddendly after it recognizes the text and print it to the textbox, to recognize other text.
I've already tried with this:

```
toggleButton.setChecked(true);
```

on the endOfSpeech method, but with no result and by bugging the speech recognition.
Is there a better solution?
Thanks in advance.